# Why is AutoCompleteExtender not firing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I have some issue with the ASP AutoCompleteExtender control. I got one in my page that is working fine, but I have put another one in the same page, and I can't get it to work. Using HTTP Analyzer, no query is fired when I type into the textbox associated with it. Has anyone an idea?

Both call the same webservice, with a different ContextKey parameter. The webservice cannot be the cause as it works in the first case (DevMgrTxtBox), and is not even called in the second (DevTxtBox). Properties of both controls are similar, I just changed the ID and targetControlID of the second.

The code below is in a ContentPlaceHolder. I'm using VS2005 with .NET 2.0. AjaxControlToolkit.dll is in version 1.0.20229.0.

---

**EDIT: solution found.** The ID is not the only thing that needs to be unique, the `BehaviorID` property must be unique too. Which wasn't documented.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <asp:Label ID="DevtMgrLbl" runat="server" Text="Development Manager"></asp:Label>                    
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="devMgrPanel">
      <contenttemplate>
        <asp:TextBox id="DevMgrTxtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender id="AutoCompleteRole1" runat="server" CompletionSetCount="5" EnableCaching="true" BehaviorID="autoCompleteExtender" CompletionInterval="100" MinimumPrefixLength="2" ServiceMethod="GetRoleList" ServicePath="AutoCompleteRoles.asmx" TargetControlID="DevMgrTxtBox" ContextKey="DM">
        </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender> 
      </contenttemplate>
      <triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DevMgrTxtBox" EventName="TextChanged"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
      </triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>                    
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <asp:Label ID="DevLbl" runat="server" Text="Developer"></asp:Label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="devPanel">
      <contenttemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="DevTxtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender id="AutoCompleteRole2" runat="server" CompletionSetCount="5" EnableCaching="true" BehaviorID="autoCompleteExtender" CompletionInterval="100" MinimumPrefixLength="2" ServiceMethod="GetRoleList" ServicePath="AutoCompleteRoles.asmx" TargetControlID="DevTxtBox" ContextKey="DEV">
    </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
      </contenttemplate>
      <triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DevTxtBox" EventName="TextChanged"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
      </triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>                    
  </td>
</tr>
```